# LEMP Docker один контейнер или связка контейнеров, что лучше?

Tags: docker, backend

Есть необходимость поднять для приложения стек nginx+php+redis+mysql.
Приложение небольшое. Изначально хотел всё сделать в одном контейнере, ибо нет необходимости  в особой устойчивости отдельных компонентов и приложение является по сути монолитом. Но не нашел более-менее вменяемых рекомендаций по компоновке такого контейнера, зато везде и всюду рекомендуют собирать связки из готовых контейнеров с помощью docker compose. Почему, разве так лучше для любых задач?

Comment: И при каждой правке в приложении вы хотите перезапускать nginx, redis и mysql. не говоря уже о том, сколько времени будет уходить на сборку образа. Как бы основная идеология докера подразумевает, один процесс - один контейнер

Comment: @Mike Зачем перезапускать? Для хранения изменяемых извне файлов есть тома.

Comment: А для чего тогда вообще нужен докер. Ставьте на систему все.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для абсолютно любых может и не лучше, т.е. вполне могут быть исключения, когда лучше запускать несолько процессов в одном контейнере. Но для большинства точно лучше запускать процессы в отдельных контейнерах из соображений удобства.

Вот подумайте. Если запускать в одном контейнере сразу возникает несколько проблем, которые в принципе не возникают, если использовать несколько контейнеров.

1. Отслеживание, какой процес запустился, какой нет.
2. Просмотр логов от отдельных процессов.
3. Контроль используемых ресурсов.
4. С отдельными контейнерами, можно использовать стандартные образы без или с минимальной конфигурацией, т.е. не нужно самому создавать образы. Это упрощает поддержку, обновление версий компонетнов делать гораздо проще. Нет перекрестных зависимостей, когда, скажем, для mysql в системе нужна одна версия системной библиотеки, а редису - другая, несовместимая.